# How to Execute SSIS Package with Configuration command line

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

there is a way (command line) to execute an SSIS Package according to one of my 2 configurations?

my command is :
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /F "C:\NicoTest\newTests1nico\Package.dtsx"

I have create a project parameter that is different according to the selected configuration - run it manually works as expected.

thanks in advance

[my 2 configurations - dev and prod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j4Nf.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to select a configuration (like it would be in visual studio/ssdt), the packages/manifest file contains the values of the selected configuration at the time of the build, there is no information in the dtsx and/or ispac file about any other configuration.

With that said, you can provide a configuration file by the `/Conf[igFile] filespec` parameter. The file provided is and XML file, commonly referenced as dtsConfig.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/cc671628(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

With that said, it might be easier to either build the project with the desired configuration, or deploy the project to an SSIS Catalog in an SQL Server, where you can override the configuration more easily.